# codeigniter form_error() not showing error beside form-control

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to show validation errors beside the form-control but form_error() is not working.
codeigniter form_error() not showing error beside form-control
The validation_errors() is working but form_error() not working beside the input control

Admin Controller

```
<?php
    class Admin extends CI_Controller
    {
        public function index()
        {
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('uname','Username','required|alpha');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass','Password','required|max_length[12]');
            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters("<div class='text-danger'>","</div>");
            if($this->form_validation->run())
            {
                echo "Validation successful";
            }
            else
            {
                //echo validation_errors();
                $this->load->view('Users/articleList');
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

The view is

```
 application/views/Users
```

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top:20px";>
        <h1> Admin Form </h1>
        <?php echo form_open('admin/index');?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Username">Username</label>
                    <?php echo form_input(['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Enter Username','name'=>'uname']);?>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <?php form_error('uname');?>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Password">Password</label>
                    <?php echo form_password(['class'=>'form-control','type'=>'password', 
                    'placeholder'=>'Enter Password', 'name'=>'pass'
                    ]);?>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <?php form_error('pass');?>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>


            <?php echo form_submit(['type'=>'submit', 'class'=>'btn btn-default','value'=>'Submit']); ?>
            <?php echo form_reset(['type'=>'submit', 'class'=>'btn btn-default','value'=>'Reset']); ?>
        </div>
<?php echo validation_errors();?>
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to echo the form_error so...

```
<?php form_error('pass');?>
```

becomes

```
<?php echo form_error('pass');?>
```

or

```
<?= form_error('pass');?>
```